# Populating the cart doesnt work (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have been trying to populate cart products in user's cart. Below is my code.

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    userName : {
        type : String,
        default : 'UserName'
    },
    cart : [ { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Cart' } ]
})

var cartSchema = new Schema({
    productNameofUser : {
        type : String,
        default : 'Product'
    }
})

var UserModel = mongoose.model('User' , userSchema)
var CartModel = mongoose.model('Cart' , cartSchema)

app.get('/users',(req,res)=>{
    UserModel.find().populate('cart').exec((err,result)=>{
        res.send(result)
    })
})
app.post('/createUser',(req,res)=>{
    let newUser = new UserModel()
    newUser.save((err,result)=>{
        console.log(result)
        res.send(result)
    })
})
app.get('/products',(req,res)=>{
    CartModel.find((err,result)=>{
        res.send(result)
    })
})
app.post('/createProduct',(req,res)=>{
    let newProduct = new CartModel()
    newProduct.save((err,result)=>{
        res.send(result)
    })
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('running')
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/populate' , { useNewUrlParser : true })
})
```

what I am trying to do is, There is a carts collection and there is another collection of users. Every user has a cart which i am trying to populate from the cart collections.

If you want to test the code, first create the user using the post link 'http://localhost:3000/createUser/' via postman and the create cart Products using 'http://localhost:3000/createProduct/' via postman. Then whenever i tried to fetch the users 'http://localhost:3000/users/' , the cart array stays empty no matter what i try.
Please figure where i am going wrong

Comment: 1st thing is We can not send  postman request  to your localhost cause ,  your  localhost is block to  outer world by  your firewall . But you can  tunnel to your  localhost to outer word by using  tools . 2nd   I think this may your error `cart : [ { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Cart' } ] ` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Hi @DibyaKrushnaDas, What do you mean it is blocked by outside world. I have been getting and posting products via postman. Are you saying the populate() cannot be seen via postman

Comment: HI @Sharan ,  it can be seen  populate  by using  postman  , I was talking some other thing , You just try with `cart : [ { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Cart' } ]`

Comment: Hi @DibyaKrushnaDas No, nothing is working from me. Did this work on yourside?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @DibyaKrushnaDas No, i am using $push to put it in array. But still i wanted to know why its not working

Answer (score 0):

Update your Schema defination as:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    userName : {
        type : String,
        default : 'UserName'
    },
    cart : [ { type : Schema .ObjectId , ref : 'Cart' } ]
})
```

And try this again:

```
app.get('/users',(req,res)=>{
    UserModel.find().populate('cart').exec((err,result)=>{
        res.send(result)
    })
})
```

Let me know, if this works now.

Comment: No, its still not working. Did this work on yourside